# Android ClassNotFoundException with ViewPager

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception, android-viewpager, inflate

I am getting the following error, which I don't understand...

```
06-15 22:06:49.196: W/dalvikvm(17622): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bcc1f8)
06-15 22:07:05.031: W/dalvikvm(17877): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bcc1f8)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.whipple.android/com.whipple.android.StockActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class ViewPager
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1968)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:561)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class ViewPager
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:272)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1851)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at com.whipple.android.StockActivity.onCreate(StockActivity.java:17)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4481)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    ... 11 more
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.ViewPager
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:636)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
06-15 22:07:05.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17877):    ... 21 more
```

This is my code...

```
public class StockActivity extends Activity {
public ListAdapter listadapter;
private StockPageAdapter myAdapter;
private ViewPager myPager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.main);

    this.myAdapter = new StockPageAdapter(this);
    this.myPager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    this.myPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}
```

It's a `ListAdapter` with a `ViewPager` to scroll through the lists. I'm extending `BaseAdapter` and inflating the view with this code...

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
```

Could someone please help me to understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

What does your XML look like in the layout file?  If you simply put

```
<ViewPager
    android:layout_width="..."
    android:layout_height="..." />
```

Your application will crash because `ViewPager` is not located in the core SDK package with other widgets, it's in the support library.  You need to put the fully qualified name

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="..."
    android:layout_height="..." />
```

Also, as others have mentioned, **make sure the support library JAR is properly included in your project**.

HTH

Comment: Yeah totally forgot about that. Changed it and now I'm on to the next error. ._. thanks though

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a few too many `super` prefixes there.

Try this:

```
@Override   
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
    setContentView(R.layout.main);   

    this.myAdapter = new StockPageAdapter(this);   
    this.myPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);   
    this.myPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);   
}
```

Also, make sure the `android-support-v4.jar` is in a directory called `libs` (which should be in your project and on the same level as `res` and `src` and `assets`).  This is a **must** now as of ADT 17 (IIRC).  Just create that directory, drop the .jar in there and Eclipse will take care of the rest, no need to try and add it manually to the build path or anything.

Comment: Yeah it's already in there. The second super is redundant but I took it out and still get the same thing.